# Is there a way to create an empty PR on purpose in Azure Devops?

Tags: azure-devops

We've got our Devops (2020 I think) server setup with various PR Build Requirements...
One is "There can't be any pending PR's into the source branch" and another is "The target branch can't be behind master".

With this combination of validations, we don't normally run into issues where we fail to include stuff in a branch that's meant to be in the branch.
The main exception to this scenario is when we have PR's pending into master, and PR's pending into another branch, at the same time.
In this scenario, it is possible for the PR's into the non-master branch to validate and complete before the PR's into master, which would have rendered the non-master branch behind and no-longer valid for those first PR's.

What I would like to do in this situation, rather than create another explicit build requirement for PR's pending into master (which might not always necessarily be deal-breakers), is to raise a PR from master into the non-master branch. This would explicitly indicate (via the "No pending PR's into source" rule) that the non-master PR's depend on the master PR's.

However, the PR from master to non-master can't be created because the non-master branch isn't behind master until the master PR's complete.

Is there any way to say "I know the target is not behind, but the PR won't pass validation until other PR's complete that will result in the source branch being updated and therefore the target being behind..." and get Devops to create it anyway?